# Adding Days using Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, date, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, momentjs

Having a few issues with simply adding a day to a few dates in an Appcelerator project using moment.js

All I want to do, is grab today's date and then display it in the DD format (01) and then get the next 6 days as well.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
var todayDate = moment();

var day1 = todayDate.format("DD");
var day2 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day3 = todayDate.add(2, 'days').format("DD");
var day4 = todayDate.add(3, 'days').format("DD");
var day5 = todayDate.add(4, 'days').format("DD");
var day6 = todayDate.add(5, 'days').format("DD");
var day7 = todayDate.add(6, 'days').format("DD");
```

But, the output I get is the following:

```
[INFO] :   31
[INFO] :   01
[INFO] :   03
[INFO] :   06
[INFO] :   10
[INFO] :   15
[INFO] :   21
```

It should read:

```
[INFO] :   31
[INFO] :   01
[INFO] :   02
[INFO] :   03
[INFO] :   04
[INFO] :   05
[INFO] :   06
```

What am I doing wrong?

Simon

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You add days to the same variable :

say `todayDate` is 31.
First line, you add 1 day to `todayDate`, so it becomes 01.
Then you add 2 days to `todayDate` (that is now "01") so it becomes 03
etc ...

Do this instead (depending on what you need of course) :

```
var day1 = moment().format("DD");
var day2 = moment().add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day3 = moment().add(2, 'days').format("DD");
var day4 = moment().add(3, 'days').format("DD");
var day5 = moment().add(4, 'days').format("DD");
var day6 = moment().add(5, 'days').format("DD");
var day7 = moment().add(6, 'days').format("DD");
```

or just add `1` every time ;)

```
var todayDate = moment();

var day1 = todayDate.format("DD");
var day2 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day3 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day4 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day5 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day6 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
var day7 = todayDate.add(1, 'days').format("DD");
```

Comment: No you're not, idiots are those who don't asks questions and believe they are doing nothing wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

You refer to the same variable

You add N days to `todayDate`, so next `add`-method will add N days to the already increased value of todays date, which is no longer 'today'